# Chrome 55: position: fixed; in div overflow: hidden; doesn't work

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I updated my chrome to version 55 and now my `position: fixed;` in a div `overflow: hidden;` doesn't work anymore.

Here is the example:
http://codepen.io/PRDev/pen/mOvwOO

```css
.container {
  background: #d3d3d3;
}

.overflow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.parallax {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #dfdfdf;
}

.next-section {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overflow">
    <div class="parallax">
      <h1>Headline</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="next-section">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

When I'm scrolling to down, the text is still visible outside div overflow hidden, on safari and chrome 54 it is hidden but not in latest Chrome 55.

On chrome 54 text in .overflow hide behind text in next-section, on chrome 55 this text in overflow is visible behind next-section

Comment: Could you please bring more clarity to the question?
I mean its obvious your 'overflow' class does not child the text in 'next-section', so why would you expect it to hide on overflow

Comment: what you need exactly

Comment: when you scroll down you want to hide `.parallax` div right ?

Comment: On chrome 54 text in .overflow is hidden behind text in .next-section, on chrome 55 this text in .overflow is visible behind .next-section

Comment: @JishnuVS yes, i want hide .parralax div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this is an issue with how overflow:hidden; works. That dictates what happens to content that overflows its parent. What you are doing is moving one div over another and the reason you see the one behind is because .next-section didnt have a background.

give `.next-section` the same bg color `background: #dfdfdf;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
.overflow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.parallax {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #dfdfdf;
}
.next-section {
  background: #dfdfdf;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overflow">
    <div class="parallax">
      <h1>Headline</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="next-section">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know that when I add background then this will works fine. This is not my problem. I have div with overflow hidden and i don't want see elements from that div outside. It work fine on previous version chrome

Comment: you are misunderstanding what the overflow property does. You have a div with overflow:hidden; which means that any content that flows outside of that div will be hidden (as oppose to a scroll bar). Well your .overflow div only contains 2 lines <h1>Headline</h1> <p>Lorem ipsum</p>. It has a height of 100vh; So there is nothing overflowing... Overflow is not what determines if the next section hides it or not. You must have changed something else.

Comment: Ok, but why this works fine on chrome 54 and older one? I want the same effect like in chrome 54, safari etc. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I have run your codepen in chrome 55, FF IE11 and Edge and they all work exactly the same. I'm not sure about safari, don't have access to it. you must have changed something else. Is your real code available on a live site I can view?

Comment: I have put this fiddle together that hopefully explains the overflow better https://jsfiddle.net/bqncdg6t/ hope its useful in understanding what overflow does and doesn't do.

Comment: You have right, I only checked this on chrome and different chrome version and safari. I must find other way to solve my problem.
Thank you for your time:)

Comment: I appreciate that perhaps you still have challenges, but given the question I think my answer does answer it. If you agree would you please mark it as such. If there's anything else I can help with let me know.